# mongodb indexes with $where

Tags: mongodb

If I write a query and filter results using $where on an indexed field, will it use the index or will it scan into each document?  For example?:

function () { return this.indexed_field > 5 }

..and yes I'm well aware I could get away with using $gt in this particular instance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an index won't be used in that case. You can run an explain() to verify.